# What is the preferred method for evolving the Nonlinear Schrödinger Equation?

Tags: pde, nonlinear-equations

I am interested in evolving the (cubic) self-focusing nonlinear Schrödinger equation,

$$i\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}+\left|\psi\right|^2\psi=0$$

from an initial condition $\psi(x,t_0)=f(x)$, where I am going to restrict my attention to a finite region $x\in [a,b]$. Since I'm not too familiar with the "standard" methods for evolving this equation, the proper choice of algorithm/method isn't obvious to me. For example, I don't know if using a "spectral" method would be better than doing straight integration/evolution. The methods I have read about are

1. [Split-Step Fourier Transform](https://www.phys.ksu.edu/personal/washburn/pdf/washburn_thesis_chapter4.pdf)
2. [Inverse Scattering Transform](http://math.arizona.edu/~mcl/Miller/MillerLecture11.pdf)
3. [Interpolation](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0045782598002576) Approaches

I would like a bit of guidance on both what is that "norm" for handling this evolution, as well as what is most efficient. I would also very much appreciate references to sources which directly or indirectly answer my question.

Please forgive me if this is a vague or overly simple question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't find universal agreement among experts on a single best way to solve this equation.  On the other hand, since it is a PDE in one spatial dimension there are many approaches that will give good accuracy in a reasonable amount of time.

A very simple place to start is a **pseudospectral discretization in space with Runge-Kutta integration in time**; you can learn about such methods in a lot of good books, or you can find a quick introduction with examples and code [here](https://github.com/ketch/PseudoSpectralPython) (disclaimer: that links to something that I wrote).

The main issue you'll find with that approach is that the second-derivative term leads to stiffness and forces you to use a time step of order $(\Delta x)^2$.  There are many ways of avoiding this restriction; the simplest is the split-step method you mention, but it introduces its own significant errors.  For other, more accurate ways to deal with the stiffness, you could look at using **an integrating factor**, **exponential methods**, or **IMEX additive Runge-Kutta methods**, all of which are discussed and tested for a variety of PDEs in [this excellent paper](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/publication/PDF/2005_111.pdf).

I won't attempt to comment on approaches 2-3 from your list, as I am not an expert on either.